# Install macOS Sierra on "Macintosh HD" or on "Update"

Tags: macos, partition, install

First time I see these two options - which should I use?

[image]

This is a 2017 MacbookPro 13" with Intel i5, model A1708, right after I erased "Macintosh HD" using Disk Utility and reset its NVRAM.

How come there are two options and what is this `Update` option?!

Answer (score 2):

Learning from [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/416331/21946), it seems I didn't fully erase the the hard drive. The proper steps are:

1. **Enter recovery mode**
   Shut down, long press power to boot, immediately hold cmd+R until you see the apple again
2. **Fully erase the drive and create partition**
   Using Disk Utility, erase the root of the tree. Be sure to name the new partition `Macintosh HD`, choose `Journaled` and `GUID Partition Map`
   [image]
   (Note: Change `Untitled` to `Macintosh HD`)
3. **Install macOS**
   If you go back and choose reinstall macOS you should now have a single drive named `Macintosh HD` to choose from